# How to fetch a wordpress admin page using google apps script?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, google-apps-script, urlfetch, http-status-code-302

I need to fetch a page inside my Wordpress blog admin area. The following script:

```
function fetchAdminPage() {
   var url = "http://www.mydomain.invalid/wp/wp-admin/wp-login.php";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "log": "admin",
      "pwd": "password",
      "wp-submit": "Login",
      "redirect_to":"http://www.mydomain.invalid/wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php",
      "testcookie": 1
      }
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   ...
}
```

is executed without errors. Anyway, `response.getContentText()` returns the login page, and I am not able to access the page http://www.mydomain.invalid/wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php which is the one I want to fetch.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you check out the value of `response.getHeaders()`? See what headers you get back. If you get a Status 200 then your credentials are most-likely incorrect(WordPress issues a Status 302 to redirect you to the dashboard or the `redirect_to` parameter upon successful login).

Comment: This is the header I receive when I use the right password: {Content-Length=1186, Expires=Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT, Set-Cookie=wordpresspass_CENSOREDSTRING=+; expires=Mon, 29-Oct-2012 09:18:51 GMT; path=/wp/, Connection=Keep-Alive, Server=Apache, X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14, Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, Pragma=no-cache, X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, Date=Tue, 29 Oct 2013 09:18:51 GMT, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding=gzip, Keep-Alive=timeout=2, max=97, Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8}

Comment: And this is the one I receive when I use the wrong password:  {Content-Length=1546, Expires=Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT, Set-Cookie=wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/wp/, Connection=Keep-Alive, Server=Apache, X-Powered-By=PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14, Cache-Control=no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, Pragma=no-cache, X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, Date=Tue, 29 Oct 2013 09:20:37 GMT, Vary=Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding=gzip, Keep-Alive=timeout=2, max=99, Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There might be an issue with Google Apps Scripts and post-ing to a URL that gives you back a redirection header.

It seems like it might not be possible to follow the redirect with a post - here's a discussion on the issue -

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754794

Would it be possible, if you modify your code to not follow redirects, capture the cookies and then do a second request to your page? I haven't actually used GAS, but here's my best guess from reading the documentation:

```
function fetchAdminPage() {
   var url = "http://www.mydomain.invalid/wp/wp-admin/wp-login.php";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "log": "admin",
      "pwd": "password",
      "wp-submit": "Login",
      "testcookie": 1
      },
      "followRedirects": false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
     // Incorrect user/pass combo
   } else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
     // Logged-in
     var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
     if ( typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Make sure that we are working with an array of cookies
        var cookies = typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] == 'string' ? [ headers['Set-Cookie'] ] : headers['Set-Cookie'];
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
           // We only need the cookie's value - it might have path, expiry time, etc here
           cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];
        };
        url = "http://www.mydomain.invalid/wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php";
        options = {
            "method": "get",
            // Set the cookies so that we appear logged-in
            "headers": {
               "Cookie": cookies.join(';')
            }
        };
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
     };
   };
   ...
}
```

You would obviously need to add some debugging and error handling, but it should get you through.

What happens here is that we first post to the log-in form. Assuming that everything goes correctly, that should give us back a response code of 302(Found). If that's the case, we will then process the headers and look specifically for the "Set-Cookie" header. If it's set, we'll get rid of the un-needed stuff and store the cookies values.

Finally we make a new get request to the desired page on the admin( in this case `/wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php` ), but this time we attach the "Cookie" header which contains all of the cookies acquired in the previous step.

If everything works as expected, you should get your admin page :)

I would advise on storing the cookies information(in case you're going to make multiple requests to your page) in order to save time, resources and requests.

Again - I haven't actually tested the code, but in theory it should work. Please test it and come back to me with any findings you make.