# Failed to log in to a website to scrape my profile name using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, cookies, urlfetch, http-status-code-302, stackexchange-api

I've been trying to log in to this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/) using my credentials in order to scrape my profile name using google apps script. The status code is 200 and I can see that the script is able to get cookies. However, I get `Undefined` as result instead of profile name.

This is how I'm trying:

```
function loginAndParseProfile() {
  var link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f';

  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
    }

  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(res.getContentText());
  var fkey = $("input[name='fkey']").first().attr('value');

  var payload = {
    'fkey': fkey,
    'ssrc': 'head',
    'email': 'emailaddress',
    'password': 'password',
    'oauth_version': '',
    'oauth_server': ''
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    'payload': payload,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
     }
    };

  var loginURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f";

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL,options);
  console.log(resp.getResponseCode());
  console.log(resp.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie']);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(resp.getContentText());
  var item = $('a.my-profile > [class^="gravatar-wrapper"]').first().attr('title');
  console.log(item);
}
```

> How can I make the script work?

Comment: What is the end goal of this request? Have you considered using the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)?

Comment: The end goal of this request is to log in to that website and scrape the profile name @Kessy.

Comment: This question is linked to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community)

Comment: Actually, the request *fails* - if you inspect the HTML closely, you get back the logged out page - this is why there is no element you are looking for. Nor is there an `acct` cookie set (this is what should be used to verify success). With that said... I dunno why the login fails - you seem to be doing everything by the book - it might be something out of our control

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567105 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794290

Comment: Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Disable redirects [by setting `followRedirects` to `false`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters_2):

   ```
   var options = {
     "method" : "post",
     'payload': payload,
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     "headers": {
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
     },
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   ```
2. Grab the `acct` cookie from the response to the `POST /users/login` request:

   ```
   const acct = resp.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie']
     .find(cookie => cookie.includes('acct=t='))
     .match(/(acct=t=.*?)\s/)[1];
   ```
3. Make a `GET /` request supplying the `acct` cookie and grab your profile name:

   ```
   const profileRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', {
     method: 'get',
     headers: {
       Cookie: acct
     }
   });

   const $main = Cheerio.load(profileRequest.getContentText());
   const myName = $main('.s-topbar--item.s-user-card > span').text();
   console.log(myName);
   ```

If your credentials are correct, this should output `robots.txt`.