# Log-in to Wordpress from google app script

Tags: wordpress, http, authentication, google-apps-script

I'm logging-in Wordpress account from google app script.

This is my try:

```
var url='http://www...it/wp-login.php';
var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "payload": {
    "log": "user",
    "pwd": "password",
    "wp-submit": "Login",
    "testcookie":'1',
  },
  "followRedirects": false,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

I get 200 code, instead of expected 302 code.

> Where I get wrong?

Other solutions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567105/how-to-fetch-a-wordpress-admin-page-using-google-apps-script), give me 404 error code.

Answer (score 1):

The 200 response code indicates that your request to fetch the desired URL was performed succesfully, while the 302 code means that you are redirected.

### The Wordpress login page will redirect you, if your log-in credentials are correct.

In other words - your request is not correct. The sample you are referring to is valid for an **ADMIN** logging into the ADMIN log-in URL. Is this also your case? Can you log-in manually if you open the URL and use the same credentials as in your Apps Script code?

Comment: The credentials are correct, because if I manually open the URL and use the same credentials I'm redicted.

Comment: In this case, given you use "followRedirects": false in your code - this is why you are not being redirected. If, however, you get an error when you enable redirecting  and follow the solution to which you referred - there must be something wrong with the way how you implement that solution, rather than the code you provide in this question.

Comment: Setting "followRedirects": true I get 200 code again, even with wrong username or password.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this in case someone else stumbles upon this question.

Things to check:

wp-submit: "Log In" or "Log+In"

Might need redirect_to field

It didn't work without passing Referer: header (doesn't seem t validate this)

Also you need to handle cookies, wp-login sets wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check

Comment: Do you have a working example per chance?  I have put something together for login  but it is just giving 200 when I think it should re-direct.